# Regarding expect_out(buffer) in Expect

Tags: tcl, expect

Can anyone explain the difference between

```
expect_out(buffer)

expect_out(0,string)
```

Generally I prefer to use `expect_out(buffer)` .

What is the second one and when can we use that?

Can any one explain please?

Answer (score 9):

You might want to take a look at the [manpage](http://www.tcl.tk/man/expect5.31/expect.1.html):

I will quote the relevant parts:

> Upon matching a pattern (or eof or full_buffer), **any matching and previously unmatched output is saved in the variable `expect_out(buffer)`**. Up to 9 regexp substring matches are saved in the variables `expect_out(1,string)` through `expect_out(9,string)`. If the `-indices` flag is used before a pattern, the starting and ending indices (in a form suitable for `lrange`) of the 10 strings are stored in the variables `expect_out(X,start)` and `expect_out(X,end)` where X is a digit, corresponds to the substring position in the buffer. 0 refers to strings which matched the entire pattern and is generated for glob patterns as well as regexp patterns. For example, if a process has produced output of `"abcdefgh\n"`, the result of:
>
> ```
> expect "cd"
> ```
>
> is as if the following statements had executed:
>
> ```
> set expect_out(0,string) cd
> set expect_out(buffer) abcd
> ```
>
> and `"efgh\n"` is left in the output buffer. If a process produced the output `"abbbcabkkkka\n"`, the result of:
>
> ```
> expect -indices -re "b(b*).*(k+)"
> ```
>
> is as if the following statements had executed:
>
> ```
> set expect_out(0,start) 1
> set expect_out(0,end) 10
> set expect_out(0,string) bbbcabkkkk
> set expect_out(1,start) 2
> set expect_out(1,end) 3
> set expect_out(1,string) bb
> set expect_out(2,start) 10
> set expect_out(2,end) 10
> set expect_out(2,string) k
> set expect_out(buffer) abbbcabkkkk
> ```

You can see how `expect_out(0,string)` and `expect_out(buffer)` contain different strings.